# c# BsonSerializer: deserialization through backing fields

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, serialization, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm starting to work with MongoDB using official c# driver. The problem is that I can't find a way to make bsonseriazer use fields (not properties) for setting the deserialized data and at the same time being able to use LINQ Api.

When mapping my class, I use BsonClassMap.FieldMap(). But this doesn't allow to use LINQ, since public properties remain unmapped.
Is there a way in BsonSerializer to do mappings based on properties, but at the same time specify that these should be set directly via their backing fields?

The reason I want to use fields for deserialization, is to omit custom validation rules that might be checked in setter.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you should keep those validation rules even when the data comes from your own database. It's much cleaner, less bug-prone and is more secure.
2. You can create your own `BsonSerializer`s (or extend an existing one) that act which ever way you want. I've made several of those and it's really simple.
3. You can have a `bool _isInitialized = false;` in your `DTO`s that you set to true right after you get items from the MongoDB driver and forgo the validation rules until it is set.

I don't see another way to "split" the mapping to both the properties (for `Linq`) and data members (for serialization) and I recommend the first option.